# Why do I still have "No Debuggable Application" in my Android Studio project?

Tags: android, android-studio

I put `android:debuggable="true"` in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I also put `debuggable true` in the build.gradle script:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug{
        debuggable true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't stopped your appplication properly while debugging your application previously. So restart your avd or phone , and Android studio. Try again. It will work.

Comment: I restarted Android Studio by going to File->Invalidate Caches/Restart->Just Restart and I also restarted my phone (Galaxy S6) but I still have "No Debuggable Application." This did not happen with previous projects. If it matters, I am using ADB over bluetooth.

Comment: @HourGlass I fixed the debugging issue, however the application says [DEAD] next to it. What does this mean?